# How do I check if a website contains a string in c++?

Tags: c++

so I am for the most part a c# coder but I am looking to switch over to c++, I am looking for an answer on how to read a website in c++ then check if it has a certain string, here is my c# code for reference.

```
string stringexample = "active";
WebClient wb = new WebClient();

string LIST = wb.DownloadString("URL");

if (LIST.Contains(stringexample))
```

Comment: There are no HTTP utilities in standard C++, you'll have to look for a library for that.

Comment: @Blaze I suppose the first step is to retreive a document through http(s). And that's a lot harder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following steps:

1. Request the page using HTTP
2. Store the response into a `std::string`
3. Use `std::string::find`.

Tricky part here is the step 1. C++ has no standard HTTP client. It doesn't have a standard networking API either. You can find the HTTP spec here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616 which you can use to implement a HTTP client. But as with all programming tasks, you can save a lot of work by using an existing implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C++ has no networking utilities but you could use `boost::asio` library to download the content of a webpage and search for the string `"active"`.

One way to do this:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("www.example.com", "http");
stream << "GET /something/here HTTP/1.1\r\n";
stream << "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
stream.flush();

std::ostringstream ss;
ss << stream.rdbuf();
std::string str{ ss.str() };

if (auto const n = str.find("active") != std::string::npos)
  std::cout << "found\n";
else
  std::cout << "nope\n";
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas DM but it just returns nope, I have tried alot but again still does not work. Could you maybe give me an example? Thanks :D